# Right configuration for HA cluster ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: high-availability, activemq-artemis

I'm new to ActiveMQ Artemis and ask community to check if I am right in configuration of HA cluster of  brokers or may be I should configure them in another way as I haven't found detailed tutorial on my case. All of the brokers run on the same machine.

**The scenario**:

There is a master node on `61617` port and two slave nodes (slave1, slave2) on ports `61618` and `61619`. If master node dies, one of slaves become active (replication mode).

It's necessary for the consumer to communicate with cluster as a "black-box". By that I  mean that the change of master (i.e. when master dies) shouldn't have any effect on consumer (i.e. the way it connects to the cluster).

What I managed to do (as I understand for this case we should configure only cluster, acceptor, and connector properties, thus I attach only this part of configuration of brokers):

**master broker:**

```
<connectors>
    <connector name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61617</connector> 
</connectors>

<ha-policy>
    <replication>
        <master/>
    </replication>   
</ha-policy>

<acceptors>
    <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61617</acceptor>
</acceptors>

<cluster-user>cluster</cluster-user>
<cluster-password>cluster</cluster-password>
<broadcast-groups>
    <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
    </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>
<discovery-groups>
    <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
    </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>
<cluster-connections>
    <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
        <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
        <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>0</max-hops>
        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
    </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

**slave 1 broker** the cluster conf is the same with master (auto-configuration when creating a node through the console --clustered)

```
<ha-policy>
    <replication>
        <slave/>
    </replication>
</ha-policy>

<connectors>
    <connector name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61618</connector>
    <connector name="netty-live-connector">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
</connectors>

<acceptors>
    <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61618 </acceptor>
</acceptors>
```

**slave 2 broker** the cluster conf is the same with master (auto-configuration when creating a node through the console --clustered)

```
<ha-policy>
    <replication>
        <slave/>
    </replication>
</ha-policy>

<connectors>
    <connector name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61619</connector>
    <connector name="netty-live-connector">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
</connectors>

<acceptors>
    <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://localhost:61619</acceptor>
</acceptors>
```

JNDI configuration in consumer :

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory=(tcp://localhost:61617?ha=true&retryInterval=1000&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.0&reconnectAttempts=10,tcp://localhost:61618?ha=true&retryInterval=1000&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.0&reconnectAttempts=10,tcp://localhost:61619?ha=true&retryInterval=1000&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.0&reconnectAttempts=10)
```

My configuration works, however I don`t sure if it is the right way it should be.

I've also found similar [question](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/How-to-setup-3-node-Artemis-2-5-0-HA-cluster-1-master-and-2-slaves-with-replication-automatic-failovs-td4737785.html) which uses static connectors. What are they doing? I don't understand how they work. Or may be that is the right way of configuration that I am looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to note is that using a single live/backup pair (or even live/backup/backup triplet) with network replication is dangerous due to the risk of "split-brain." I would recommend you use either 1 live/backup pair with shared-storage or 3 live/backup pairs with replication (which will allow the establishment of a proper quorum). Read [the documentation about split brain](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/network-isolation.html) for more details.

Aside from the risk of split-brain the broker configuration looks OK. Most (if not all) the configuration details are covered in the [clustering](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html) and [HA](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html) documentation. There is also a wealth of examples which ship with the broker many of which are specific to clustering and HA.

You could simplify your connection factory URL. Currently you have:

```
(tcp://localhost:61617?ha=true&retryInterval=1000&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.0&reconnectAttempts=10,tcp://localhost:61618?ha=true&retryInterval=1000&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.0&reconnectAttempts=10,tcp://localhost:61619?ha=true&retryInterval=1000&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.0&reconnectAttempts=10)
```

However, you could use:

```
(tcp://localhost:61617,tcp://localhost:61618,tcp://localhost:61619)?ha=true&retryInterval=1000&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.0&reconnectAttempts=10
```

Static connectors are typically used in environments which don't support UDP multicast. It allows manual configuration of the cluster members. If you are in an environment which supports UDP multicast I recommend you use the discovery/broadcast groups configuration rather than static discovery.

In general, if everything is working the way you want that indicates your configuration is fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing and answering to my questions. I always read documentation firstly, however as i am new to MQ systems on the whole, I want to  make sure I understand the topic right.

Comment: Is this still right way to create HA cluster?  I am very new to Artemis and came across https://devpress.csdn.net/k8s/62fcf307c6770329308025e2.html. I am finding online documentation bit confusing.

Comment: @binarymemoir, I recommend you ask a _new_ question with details about your use-case. This answer is over 3 years old now and new features for high-availability have been implemented since then. It will be difficult to explain everything in the comments here.